# How do I solve for P? Inverse of modulo?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm working on a code [challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/help-the-general-decode-secret-enemy-messages/train/javascript), and I've figured out how messages are encoded, now I just need to reverse the process.

The device encodes strings as such:

For each character $c$ in the string $S$, replace it with the character at position $C$ of $key$ where:

$C = ((P + 1)2^{i + 1} - 1) \% L - d$

> $i$ is the position of $c$ in $S$ (known)
>
> $P$ is the position of $c$ in $key$
>
> $L$ is the length of $key$ (known $L=67$)
>
> $\%$ is the modulus operator
>
> $d$ is either $1$ or $0$ depending on a condition ($i>46$)

If $C$ is known, how do I go about solving for $P$? I did a few searches for the inverse of modulus, but I'm not grokking how to apply that here.

Comment: There is no actual inverse of the modulus operation, for the simple reason that `5%3==8%3==2`, so the inverse of `2` is both `5` and `8` (and a lot of others as well) simultaneously. That's not a good property for an operation to have, not even an inverse. That is why you haven't gotten any results. However, working modulo $L$, there might be an inverse to "add $1$, multiply by $2^{i+1}$, then subtract $1$". At least as long as $L$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you know (or can guess) $d$, you want $P$ with $1 \le P \le L$ and
$ C + d + 1\equiv (P+1) 2^{i+1} \mod L$.

If $L$ is odd, you can do this, because $2$ is invertible mod $L$.  In fact, since  $2 ((L+1)/2) \equiv 1 \mod L$, you have
$$P+1 \equiv (C+d+1) ((L+1)/2)^{i+1} \mod L$$

If $L$ is even, there might not be any solution at all, and if there is one it is not unique.

Comment: Thanks! This has gotten me closer. I'm getting the correct result for the first 12 characters.

$P = ((C + d + 1)((L + 1)/2)^{i + 1}) \% L - 1$

I assume I'm missing a step.